How to detect Android/iOS theme (light or dark mode) using Python script?
I'm trying to create an ui-automation script using Python for mobile devices. Currently, I'm using snapshot to recognize either the device is in light or dark mode. I realize that this method is not effective if I'm doing it for many different apps.
Therefore I wanted to create a function that can detect current device theme so it's more device-oriented instead of app-oriented.
Is it possible to detect Android/iOS theme (light or dark mode) using Python script?

Run python script using swift. - https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/30092?answerId=177152022#177152022
